# opensaml3 symetric key transport and encryption

Tags: encryption, assertion, opensaml

I'm working with ECC (eliptic curve) keys and opensaml 3.4.5.
I need to encrypt my assertion with symetric key (AES256-GCM) and then transport it using KW-AES256 by encoding symetric key with recipient's public key from jks.

The problem im facing is from org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Encrypter class which wont allow me to encrypt symetric key with ECPublicKey throwing error:

> Attempt made to use EC key for encrypted key transport -
> EC keys may not be used for encrypted key transport

But what it does inside is always taking public key from credentials:

```
CredentialSupport.extractEncryptionKey(kekParams.getEncryptionCredential());
Key key = CredentialSupport.extractEncryptionKey(kekParams.getEncryptionCredential());
        if (key == null) {
            this.log.error("Key encryption credential and contained key are required");
            throw new EncryptionException("Key encryption credential and contained key are required");
        } else if (key instanceof DSAPublicKey) {
            this.log.error("Attempt made to use DSA key for encrypted key transport");
            throw new EncryptionException("DSA keys may not be used for encrypted key transport");
        } else if (key instanceof ECPublicKey) {
            this.log.error("Attempt made to use EC key for encrypted key transport");
            throw new EncryptionException("EC keys may not be used for encrypted key transport");
        } else if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(kekParams.getAlgorithm())) {
            this.log.error("Key encryption algorithm URI is required");
            throw new EncryptionException("Key encryption algorithm URI is required");
        }
[...]
@Nullable
public static Key extractEncryptionKey(@Nullable Credential credential) {
    if (credential == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (Key)(credential.getPublicKey() != null ? credential.getPublicKey() : credential.getSecretKey());
    }
}
```

The first thing that i do is generate symetric key as follows:

```
Credential symmetricCredential = AlgorithmSupport.generateSymmetricKeyAndCredential(EncryptionConstants.ALGO_ID_BLOCKCIPHER_AES256_GCM);
```

Then im building DataEncryptionParameters for my assertion:

```
DataEncryptionParameters dataEncryptionParameters = new DataEncryptionParameters();
            dataEncryptionParameters.setEncryptionCredential(symmetricCredential);
            dataEncryptionParameters.setAlgorithm(EncryptionConstants.ALGO_ID_BLOCKCIPHER_AES256_GCM);
```

Next is KeyEncryptionParameters object:

```
KeyEncryptionParameters keyEncryptionParameters = new KeyEncryptionParameters();
            keyEncryptionParameters.setEncryptionCredential(getCredentials(alias));
            keyEncryptionParameters.setAlgorithm(EncryptionConstants.ALGO_ID_KEYWRAP_AES256);
```

getCredentials method reads key from jks by alias and creating credentials for it:

```
public Credential getCredentials(String alias) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = readKeyStoreFromFile();
            Map<String, String> passwordMap = new HashMap<>();
            if(keyStore.entryInstanceOf(alias, KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.class)){
                log.debug(alias + " is private key, initiating password for this alias");
                passwordMap.put(alias, jksPassword);
            } else {
                log.debug(alias + " is trusted cert, no need to initiate password for this alias");
            }

            KeyStoreCredentialResolver resolver = new KeyStoreCredentialResolver(keyStore, passwordMap);
            Criterion criterion = new EntityIdCriterion(alias);
            CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet();
            criteriaSet.add(criterion);
            return resolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
        } catch (ResolverException | KeyStoreException e) {
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            throw new DomainError("OpenSAML failed to resolve criteria set for credentials");
        }
    }
```

And finally declaring and using Encryptor class:

```
Encrypter encrypter = new Encrypter(dataEncryptionParameters, keyEncryptionParameters);
encryptedAssertion = encrypter.encrypt(assertion);
```

I'm wondering whether these whole idea make sense, cause from what I've read the aes is symetric so i should encrypt with my private key and if it does why opensaml classes are contradictory on this issue.

Comment: Er, you do understand that `ALGO_ID_KEYWRAP_AES256` uses an AES key to wrap another key, right? See [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3394.txt). In other words, it is the *wrapping mechanism* not the key type of the *wrapped key*. You can encrypt with e.g. an RSA public key (using RSA OAEP or the older / less secure PKCS#1 v1.5 padding). You **never** encrypt with a private key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for your answer, but can u tell me the reason why i cant encrypt with public ec key?

Comment: Well, you can, kind of. There is no specific encryption operation for ECC that is like RSA-encrypt. There is ElGamal, but that requires that the message is transformed into a point on the curve, and that the message is very small, so it is commonly not used. You could however use ECIES. That's a very roundabout way of using DH key agreement to encrypt data, but apparently that's not available in the protocol or protocol implementation (I'd have to look that up).